# How to used own cordova plugin in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have one question regarding the IONIC 4. I have existing project which has installed the own cordova plugin and it working fine. I want to upgrade the app to Ionic 4 But with Ionic I am able move the plugin in Ionic 4.

Because In Ionic 4 plugin has been loaded from ngx folder. I have added the plugin in plugin folder and as well as in platform folder with following command:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-test
ionic cordova prepare android
```

Can any one help me how to import this plugin in App module and used it